# MDX Calculated Member in where clause

Tags: sql, ssas, mdx

I am new to MDX queries.  I have the following query and would like to limit the results to only show records where the Margin Pct is > 0.  Any help would appreciated.

```
WITH 
    MEMBER [Measures].[Margin Pct] as ([Measures].[Mgmt Margin Excluding Markup]/[Measures].[Net Sales])*100,format_string="0.0" 
    MEMBER [Measures].[Mgmt Margin] as [Measures].[Mgmt Margin Excluding Markup],format_string="0.0" 
    MEMBER [Measures].[Mgmt Cost Unit] as [Measures].[Mgmt Cost Unit Excluding Markup],format_string="0.00" 
    MEMBER [Measures].[FOBPrce] as [Measures].[FOB Price],format_string="0.00" 
    MEMBER [Measures].[CommUnt] as [Measures].[Comm/Unit],format_string="0.000" 
    MEMBER [Measures].[RebUnt] as [Measures].[Reb/Unit],format_string="0.00" 
    MEMBER [Measures].[FrtUnt] as [Measures].[Frt/Unit],format_string="0.00" 
    MEMBER [Measures].[PriceUnt] as [Measures].[Price/Unit],format_string="0.00"
SELECT NON EMPTY { 
    [Measures].[Rpt Inv Shp Date], 
    [Measures].[Lbs Shipped],
    [Measures].[Net Sales], 
    [Measures].[FOBPrce], 
    [Measures].[CommUnt], 
    [Measures].[RebUnt], 
    [Measures].[FrtUnt], 
    [Measures].[PriceUnt], 
    [Measures].[Mgmt Cost Unit], 
    [Measures].[Mgmt Margin], 
    [Measures].[Margin Pct] 
} ON COLUMNS, NON EMPTY { 
    (
        [Item].[Group Sort].[Group Sort],
        [Item].[Form Sort].[Form Sort],
        [Item].[Specie Sort].[Specie Sort],
        {[Item].[Group thru Item ID].[Group].ALLMEMBERS},
        [Shrimp Group].[Shrimp Group].[Shrimp Group Name].ALLMEMBERS ,
        {[Item].[Form].[Form].ALLMEMBERS},
        [Item].[Meat - In Shell].[Meat or Inshell].ALLMEMBERS , 
        [Item].[Super Specie].[Super Specie].ALLMEMBERS ,
        {[Item].[Species].[Species].ALLMEMBERS},
        {[Item].[Item ID].[Item ID].ALLMEMBERS},
        [Item].[Desc-ItemID].[Item ID Description].ALLMEMBERS , 
        [Item].[Package Type].[Packaging].ALLMEMBERS ,
        {[Brand].[Brand].[Brand Name].ALLMEMBERS},
        {[Warehouse].[Warehouse].[Warehouse Code].ALLMEMBERS},
        [Order Invoice Lot].[Order-Invoice-Lot].[Lot].ALLMEMBERS ,
        {[Customer Account Number].[Customer Account No].Levels(1)},
        {[Ship To Customer].[Customer Name].Levels(1)},
        {[Sales Person].[Person].Levels(1)},
        [Order Invoice Lot].[Sales Order].[Sales Order].ALLMEMBERS , 
        [Order Invoice Lot].[Invoice].[Invoice].ALLMEMBERS
    ) 
} DIMENSION PROPERTIES MEMBER_CAPTION, MEMBER_UNIQUE_NAME ON ROWS FROM (
    SELECT StrToSet( '{[Breaded Group].[Breaded Group].[All]}' ,CONSTRAINED ) ON COLUMNS FROM (
    SELECT StrToSet( '{[Inventory Category].[Inventory Category].[All]}' ,CONSTRAINED ) ON COLUMNS FROM (
    SELECT StrToSet( '{[Sold To Customer].[Customer Buying Group].[All]}' ,CONSTRAINED ) ON COLUMNS FROM (
    SELECT StrToSet( '{[Ship To Customer Sales Group].[Ship To Customer Sales Group].[All]}' ,CONSTRAINED ) ON COLUMNS FROM (
    SELECT StrToSet( '{[Sold To Customer].[Customer Legal Group].[All]}' ,CONSTRAINED ) ON COLUMNS FROM (
    SELECT StrToSet( '{[Country Of Origin].[Long Name].[All]}' ,CONSTRAINED ) ON COLUMNS FROM (
    SELECT StrToSet( '{[Is Sample].[Sample].[Description].[Regular]}' ,CONSTRAINED ) ON COLUMNS FROM (
    SELECT StrToSet( '{[Invoicing Status].[Invoicing Status-Detail].[Detail].[Sale Only],[Invoicing Status].[Invoicing Status-Detail].[Detail].[Credit Only]}' ,CONSTRAINED ) ON COLUMNS FROM (
    SELECT StrToSet( '{[Invoice Date].[Fiscal Year-Quarter-Month].[Fiscal Month].[Jul-FY13]}' ,CONSTRAINED ) ON COLUMNS FROM (
    SELECT StrToSet( '{[Sold To Customer].[Name].[All]}' ,CONSTRAINED ) ON COLUMNS FROM (
    SELECT StrToSet( '{[Is NRV].[NRV].[All]}' ,CONSTRAINED ) 
ON COLUMNS FROM [FishTrackerReporting] ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) ) )
```

I have tried to use a where clause against the [Measures].[Margin Pct] but get this error:

The WHERE clause function expects a tuple set expression for the  argument. A string or numeric expression was used.

I also tried to use a filter after the on columns part of the query but get out of memory issues so I think I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Too bad the reference of MDX is not the best. You can use `HAVING` or `FILTER` to achieve what you want. I'd go with `HAVING` since it's easier to use.

Please have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms146052.aspx) and find the last example.

Comment: Looks like the having clause may do what I want.  I will check when I get home and accept answer if it works, thanks :)

Comment: Added the having clause and it worked like a charm.  Thank you.